# Firebase data insert is not working even it say connected to app

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to insert the data in the firebase database but it is working. It says it is connected by whenever I run my application, the value does not get updated. 
Here is my User.class

```
public class User {
   public String username;
   public int value;

   public User() {
      // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
   }

   public User(String username, int value) {
       this.username = username;
       this.value = value;
   }

 public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

public int getValue(){
    return value;
}
}
```

HERE In MY TEST.JAVA, i have

```
 DatabaseReference myRef;
 myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Score");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                maxid = (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
 //In order to add the value to the database
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = text1.getText().toString();
            int value = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());
            User user = new User("mohan", 111);
            myRef.child(String.valueOf(maxid + 1)).push().setValue(user);
            text1.setText("");
            text2.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Data Inserested", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

I press the button but the value will not be added in the console.

Comment: Why didn't you use set methods for your User class?

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: @majuran will that make any difference using the constructor or set methods?  I tried it but still does not work.

Comment: @Abhinav No its doesnot give me any error.

Comment: Can you show your realtime db structure?

Comment: Can you remove .push() and try again

Comment: @mohankarki if you want to read from realtime database, You need setters aswell. Why are you skipping that? Make sure you have getters and setters

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I tried by removing it too.

Comment: @majuran oh okay, I will make sure to have it now. what else you think I can do?

Comment: Did you try, is the still same error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, It is working fine

The problem may be the reason of your [Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security). Just change your rules to public like below code

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

and try again.

> Note: It is not good to open to public for reading and writing in
>   production. For testing purpose use it open

Comment: Yes, the rule is currently true for both read and write. Is there any way, this kind of problem may occur??

Comment: `btn1` was not initialized properly or Your `maxid` may be null